# ToolTips in iOS through native UI Controls?

Tags: ios, cocoa, touch, tooltip

How do I create tooltips or something similar in iOS, without using any third party classes? I have a UIButton that I'd like to have a tooltip popup for a few seconds or until it's cleared. I have seen third party classes and libraries, but want to know if natively it's supported. I also want to show an arrow popping up from where the tooltip is coming from. I've seen some UIActionSheet Popups have this arrow.

Cheers,
Amit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I ended up using the third party tooltip [CMTopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView) afterall. It's relatively low overhead, just a header and implementation. Modified it slightly to account for ARC.  Here is what I did:

```
#import "CMPopTipView.h"

CMPopTipView *navBarLeftButtonPopTipView;

- (void) dismissToolTip
{
   [navBarLeftButtonPopTipView dismissAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) showDoubleTap
{
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView = [[CMPopTipView alloc] 
       initWithMessage:@"DOUBLE Tap \n to view details"] ;
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.delegate = self;
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.textColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.opaque = FALSE;
    [navBarLeftButtonPopTipView presentPointingAtView:catButton1 
        inView:self.view animated:YES];
    navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.alpha = 0.75f;

    NSTimer *timerShowToolTip = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
     target:self 
     selector:@selector(dismissToolTip) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on iPad you could use `UIPopoverView`. You also have the `UIMenuController` to work with for 'popover' like functionality on iPhone or iPad: [tutorial](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-szumski/getting-started-uimenucontroller-ios-5). Beyond that you could just make your own `UIView` subclass to do this but then you'd have to handle the arrow yourrself.

Comment: both are great ideas, but i ended up going another direction. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @AmitApollo which way?

Comment: I used CMPopTipView (third party control) to adjust it's size and opacity and fading alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Well what I ended up doing was relatively simple. I ended up using UIActionSheet with no Buttons just a text. Then used a showFromRect from a coordinate plane where the UIButton was in self.view.

```
UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"DOUBLE Tap \n to view details." 
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

[popup sizeToFit];
popup.tag = 9999; 
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(240.0f, 605.0f, 30.0f, -40.0f);
[popup showFromRect:myImageRect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

I may just suck it up and use CMPopTipView (third party control) to adjust it's size and opacity and fading alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that some of you is using CMPopTip, great "library".
Cool way!

Just a few things, if you use that in iOS7, you have some deprecation.

New use of the text deprecated part (this is an example)

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.titleAlignment;

    [self.title drawInRect:titleFrame withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.titleFont,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
```

Bye!